# Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1

Tags: error, downloadable, frontend-error

i have this error when i click on in the user panel on My Downloadable Products

I hope anyone can help me

```
2016-12-13T22:33:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given  in /home/blueb/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php on line 315
```

In Abstract.php is this line on 315

```
/**
     * Retrieve layout object
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Layout
     */
    public function getLayout()
    {
        return $this->_layout;
    }
```

Comment: It's saying your _layout is not a string.  You could convert it?  What is the _layout variable right now?

Comment: i found a solution. in the standard template file

/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml

echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable'))->__('Start Download')

to this

echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download'))

is a error

edit this.

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution. in the standard template file /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downl‌​oadable/customer/pro‌​ducts/list.phtml

edit this

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable‌​'))->__('Start Download')
```

to this

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable‌​')->__('Start Download')) is a error edit this.
```

this is in the standard template file on 1.9.2.4
i look at 1.9.3.1 and there is the same error